# Adding “active” class to menu not working for files inside _data folder - jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to add an "active" class to the categories on my main menu when the category is opened and also for the category when a single post in that category is opened. All posts in the `_posts` folder are in folders bearing the category names. I can get the active class to work when I hard code all the menu items like this

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
      <li {% if page.url contains '/category/name/' or page.path contains "_posts/category-name" %}class="active" aria-current="page"{% endif %}><a href="/category/name/">Category Name</a></li>
    </ul>
```

But it does not work if I create the navigation inside a nav.yaml file like this

```
- title: Category Name
  url: /category/name/
  path: _posts/category-name
```

and then add this to header.html

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
      {% for nav in site.data.nav %}
      <li {% if page.url contains '{{nav.url}}' or page.path contains "{{nav.path}}" %}class="active" aria-current="page"{% endif %}><a href="{{nav.url}}">{{nav.title}}</a></li>
     {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

I am trying not to hard code the menu items, so my question is, how do I get the items in the `_data` file to work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The double curly braces are not replaced in your condition. You can just use the variable immediately.

Instead of

```
{% if page.url contains '{{nav.url}}' %}
```

write

```
{% if page.url contains nav.url %}
```